# 'unbound variable' error when using function-level bash trap (trap ... RETURN)

Tags: bash, shell-script, function, trap

Consider this script that calls into a function that sets up a `trap` for the `RETURN` of that function:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail

function f1() {
  local temp_file
  temp_file="$(mktemp)"
  trap 'echo DELETED; rm -- "${temp_file}"' RETURN
  date > temp_file
}

function main() {
  for i in $(seq 0 2); do
    f1
  done
}

main
```

For some reason this prints `DELETED` string 4 times (instead of 3) and fails with an `unbound variable` error:

```
DELETED
DELETED
DELETED
DELETED
hack/deploy-example-server.sh: line 13: temp_file: unbound variable
```

Clearly, something is causing an extra execution of this `trap`, I'm suspecting it's the overall script's exit.

This does not happen if I eliminate `function main`, and just call `f1` in a for-loop in the top-level script.

What's causing this behavior?

Comment: I believe it's the return from main() that causes the extra execution but the whole thing looks like a specification-by-implementation bug to me.

Comment: The `RETURN` trap will be executed for all the callers through to the main script. Example: `bash -c 'foo(){ bar; }; bar(){ baz; }; baz(){ trap "echo \${FUNCNAME[@]}" RETURN; }; foo'`. I wasn't able to find this clearly mentioned anywhere.

Comment: btw, if you copied my example in a file and run it as `bash file`, you would see that it's not a good idea to call a function `main` in bash.

Answer (score 0):

Any `trap` you set is global.

The fourth trap happens when `main()` returns.  At this point, the `local` variable `temp_file` is no longer set.  (Hence the `unbound variable` error.)

Consider unsetting the trap in `main()` after the `for` loop.  I think you can unset the trap with `trap RETURN`.

Alternatively (and preferably?), consider using something other than `trap`.

Option 1: Append each file you want to delete to an array, and then explicitly delete those files later on.

Option 2: Wrap function `f1()` with another function `f2()`, and have `f2()` delete the file.  Perhaps someting like the below (which I have not tested):

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail

function trace() {
  #  usage:  trace  command  [arg ...]
  echo  "+  $*"  1>&2
  "$@"
}

function f1() {
  true    #  replace true with your code
}

function f2() {
  #  usage:  f2  func_name
  local func_name="$1"
  local temp_file="$(mktemp)"
  "$func_name"
  trace  rm  --  "$temp_file"
}
    
function main() {
  for i in $(seq 0 2); do
    f2  f1
  done
}

main
```